# Analyze Html Content - in Java

Tags: java, html, web

I was tasked to analyze content of Html page using Java, and export these web page data into well formated pdf. I have already set up my technology stack using Jsoup for parsing Html and Apache PDFBox for exporting this web page into pdf.

But where im stucked is, what data should i export,how do i find in prased Html  which data are interesting which not , how to well format them etc. Are there any Studies, where i can read more about how to analyze html content , by priorities. Which data are important which are not.
The only one i know is to analyze priorities by html tags  is more prioritized then  and so on.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help

Comment: "how do i find in prased Html which data are interesting which not" <. Since "interesting" is an enterily subjective term this cannot be answered. We have no idea what data you or your employer want. You should probably just ask the person who gave you the task what exactly he wants analyzed.

Comment: its an interview task and it should be generalized , well my task is to Parse Web Page into well formated pdf, and i have problem with how to lead this analyzis of web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this documentation page: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html
You will probably have some entries or patterns to find in the HTML, so you just need to adapt the JSOUP Selector pattern to those variables.